# What semantics of `require()` make class definitions unavailable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, require

I have a file allocation.js which defines `class Allocation {...}`.  I have another file, test.js, which has `require('./allocation.js')` and on the next line `a = new Allocation;` which generates `ReferenceError: Allocation is not defined`.  If I paste the contents of allocation.js into test.js where the `require` is and comment out the `require`, the code works fine.  Is it possible to separate class definitions out into other files and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*If I paste the contents of allocation.js into test.js*" that's not what `require` does. It only includes exported items. And it does not dump them in the outer scope, either, you still need to reference them explicitly, e.g., `const Allocation = require('./allocation.js')` which will allow you to use `new` with it. allocation.js still needs to export the class, though. It's a module.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the class from the file.

```js
module.exports = Allocation;
```

Then you can import it in the other file.

```js
var Allocation = require('./allocation.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects of `require` that I needed to know:

1. `require` is NOT part of Javascript, but rather part of node.js, and it only has the ability to return an object.
2. `require` allows the code to process another file, "treated as a module", which has its own scope.  In order for the caller of `require` to use anything defined in that (other) scope, it must be set as a property of module.exports, which is the return value of the `require` function.

The scoping of the required file is the main reason that inserting its contents works but `require` does not, at least not the way I did it.  @Fastnlight shows how to "import" the class definition into the calling file, and how to expose it from the file you `require`.

While finding this answer, I also ran into the the "exports" shortcut, which is that in a file, the keyword `exports` is the same object as module.exports, and so if you want to expose something, you can make it a property of exports (or of module.exports, which is the same thing).  You can also make `require` return whatever you want with `module.exports = (whatever you want)`, but this does not work with `exports = (whatever you want)` because you are overwriting the value instead of adding a property, and after `exports = (whatever you want)`, exports will be thrown away and invisible to the caller.

I learned this from https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v16.x/api/modules.html#modules-commonjs-modules